# Как исправить ошибку генетического алгоритма с нейронной сетью

Tags: python, массивы, машинное-обучение, keras, генетический-алгоритм

Я пытаюсь сделать генетический алгоритм с нейронной сетью, который играет в мою среду Geometry Dash, но у меня возникает ошибка:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer:
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but received input
with shape (32, 1)

которая переводится как:

ValueError: Ввод 0 из последовательного слоя несовместим со слоем:
ожидалось, что ось -1 входной формы будет иметь значение 192, но
получен ввод с формой (32, 1)

Ниже будут приведены коды, кроме физики моей среды, которые помогут понять ошибку.

```python
import random
from physics import Engine, Constructions
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer

P_MUTATION = 0.9#вероятность мутации
POPULATION_SIZE = 5
MAX_GENERATIONS = 50
GENS = []#список генов сразу же несколько особей
BRAINS = []

tk = Tk(); canvas = Canvas()
tk.quit(); tk.destroy()

music = False

players = []
players_results = []
PlayersAmount = 0

def CreateIndividuals(amount):
    global PlayersAmount
    PlayersAmount = amount

def play():
    global players_results, players, created_objects, Engine, Constructions
    if music == True:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load("audio.mp3")
        mixer.music.play()

    players = []
    players_results = []
    for n in range(PlayersAmount):
        players.append(True)
        players_results.append(0)

    reset = False

    Engine.Createpaddle(colorfill='darkcyan', coloroutline='white')#создание пола

    Constructions.bridge(x=15, y=0, length=5, height=2, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline = 'white', name='bridge1')#создание уровня
    Constructions.bridge(x=23, y=0, length=5, height=4, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline = 'white', name='bridge2')
    Constructions.recumbent_pillar(x=31, y=2, length=5, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline = 'white', name='rec_pillar1')
    Constructions.spike(x=32.5, y=3, colorfill='gray', coloroutline = 'white', name='spike1', level=2)
    Constructions.spike_recumbent_pillar(x=31, y=0, length=8, colorfill='darkred', coloroutline = 'black', name='spike_rec_pillar1')
    Constructions.pillar(x=40, y=0, height=4, colorfill='darkorange', coloroutline = 'white', name='pillar1')
    Constructions.pillar(x=44, y=0, height=2, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline = 'white', name='pillar2')
    Engine.CreateObject(x=44, y=3, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline='white', objecttype='block', name='block1')
    Engine.CreateObject(x=44, y=4, colorfill='gray', coloroutline='white', objecttype='death_block', name='spike2')
    Constructions.spike(x=46, y=0, colorfill='gray', coloroutline = 'white', name='spike3', level=3)
    Constructions.recumbent_pillar(x=49, y=0, colorfill='mediumblue', coloroutline = 'white', length=13, name='rec_pillar2')
    Constructions.spike(x=53, y=1, colorfill='pink', name='spike4', coloroutline = 'white', level=2)

    for n in range(PlayersAmount):#создание игроков
        Engine.CreateObject(x=3, y=0, colorfill='yellow', coloroutline='black', name='player'+str(n), objecttype='player')

    Engine.StartSimulation()#запуск симуляции

    while True:
        Engine.MoveObjects()
        for n in range(PlayersAmount):#проверка на смерть игроков
            if players[n] == True:
                 if Engine.GetGameStatus(playername='player'+str(n)) == 'Negative':
                     Engine.DeleteObject(name='player'+str(n))
                     players[n] = False
                 else:
                    players_results[n] += 1

        for n in range(PlayersAmount):#проверка на надобность ресета при победе
            if players[n] == True:
                 if Engine.GetGameStatus(playername='player'+str(n)) == 'Positive':
                     reset = True
                     created_objects = False

        if players.count(True) == 0:#проверка на надобность ресета при проигрыше
            reset = True
            created_objects = False

        if reset == True:#ресет
            Engine.DeleteAllObjects()
            break

        '''for n in range(PlayersAmount):  # можно ли прыгать игрокам
            if random.randint(0, 30) == 0 and players[n] == True:
                Engine.Jump(name='player' + str(n))'''

        for n in range(PlayersAmount):
            x_train = Engine.GetObjectPosAndTypeInWindow(maxinfo=64)
            while len(x_train) != 192:
                x_train.append(0)
            x_train = np.array(x_train)
            x_train.ravel()
            print(x_train.shape[0])
            print(x_train)
            if Brain.ModelPredict(x_train_array=x_train, name=BRAINS[n]) == 1 and players[n] == True:
                Engine.Jump(name='player' + str(n))


def getresultslist():
    return players_results

def getplayerslist():
    return players


from cubebrain import *

def CreatePopulation(individuals):
    global BRAINS
    BRAINS = []
    CreateIndividuals(amount=individuals)
    for n in range(individuals):
        BRAINS.append(None)
        BRAINS[n] = Brain.CreateBrain(name = 'brain'+str(n))

def GetBinaryBrainResult(name: str, x_train_list):
    return Brain.ModelPredict(x_train_list, name=name)

def FitnessMax():
    pass

def Mutation(P_MUTATION):
    pass

def selTournament():
    getresultslist().index(max(getresultslist()))

def fit():
    play()

CreatePopulation(individuals=2)

fit()

while True:
    if getplayerslist().count(True) == 0:
        selTournament()
        fit()
    #print(Engine.GetObjectPosAndTypeInWindow(maxinfo=2))
```

Ниже есть код с нейронной сетью (я только недавно начал понимать как работают классы, раньше как-то обходился одними функциями):

```js
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras, layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import*
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import*

class Brain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = []
        self.brains = []
    def CreateBrain(self, name: str):
        for item in self.models:
            if self.models.count(item) > 1:
                raise MemoryError('Invalid name. Recurring names: %s' % item)
        self.models.append(name)
        self.brains.append(None)


        self.brains[len(self.brains) - 1] = keras.Sequential([
            Dense(units=32, input_shape=(192,), activation='relu', name='dense1'), Dropout(0.3),
            Dense(units=1, activation='softmax', name='dense2')
        ])

        #print(self.brains[len(self.brains) - 1].summary())

        self.brains[len(self.brains) - 1].compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.adam_v2.Adam(0.01))
        return self.models[len(self.brains) - 1]

    def ModelPredict(self, x_train_array, name: str):
        print(len(x_train_array))
        if name not in self.models: raise NameError('There is no such name')
        return self.brains[self.models.index(name)].predict(x_train_array)

    def GetWeights(self, name: str):#веса должны быть возращены в виде массива
        if name not in self.models: raise NameError('There is no such name')
        return self.brains[self.models.index(name)].get_weights()

    def SetWeights(self, weights, name: str):
        if name not in self.models: raise NameError('There is no such name')
        self.brains[self.models.index(name)].set_weights(weights)

    def GetNWeights(self):
        return 6209
Brain = Brain()
```

Ошибка была совершена в 96-й строке первого кода, часть которого выглядит:

```js
        for n in range(PlayersAmount):
            x_train = Engine.GetObjectPosAndTypeInWindow(maxinfo=64)
            while len(x_train) != 192:
                x_train.append(0)
            x_train = np.array(x_train)
            x_train.ravel()
            print(x_train.shape[0])
            print(x_train)

            #ОШИБКА СОВЕРШЕНА В ФУНКЦИИ Brain.ModelPredict()

            if Brain.ModelPredict(x_train_array=x_train, name=BRAINS[n]) == 1 and players[n] == True:
                Engine.Jump(name='player' + str(n))
```

Ещё ниже приведён код, который является функцией `Engine.GetObjectPosAndTypeInWindow(maxinfo=64)`:

```js
    def GetObjectPosAndTypeInWindow(self, maxinfo):
        self.help_verable = []
        self.help_verable2 = 0
        for n in range(self.objectamount):
            if self.x1[n] > 0 and self.x2[n] < WIDTH and self.objecttype[n] != 'player':# ++++++++++++ yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                self.help_verable2 += 1
                self.help_verable.append((math.ceil(self.x1[n] + self.x2[n])/2))
                self.help_verable.append((math.ceil(self.y1[n] + self.y2[n]) / 2))
                self.help_verable.append(-1 if self.objecttype[n] == 'block' else 1)
            if self.help_verable2 == maxinfo:
                break
        return self.help_verable
```

Answer (score 0):

В коде ошибки на 96-й строке надо внести поправку:

```py
x_train = np.array([x_train])
```

PS: добавились квадратные скобки